# Find better way to see if object has filled fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I got the filter in Vue.

Template:

```
<b-button v-if="filterFilled()" @click="clearFilter">
    Clear
</b-button>
```

Data:

```
data () {
      return {
        filter: {
          price_from: '',
          price_to: '',
          surface_from: '',
          surface_to: '',
          floor: '',
          type: '',
          structure: '',
        },
      }
    },
```

And my method where I check is filter dirty:

```
filterFilled(){
        return (this.filter.price_from || this.filter.price_to || this.filter.surface_to || this.filter.surface_from ||
          this.filter.floor || this.filter.type || this.filter.structure)
      },
```

This works fine, but my question is, **does it exists better way to ask if object has filled props?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if `this.filter` has at least one [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
filterFilled() {
  return Object.values(this.filter).some(v => v)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @adiga suggestion, for methods that checks over data in your component, you should generally prefer [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) over methods, since they are more performant and only called when some of its dependencies change:

```
...

data () {
      return {
        filter: {
          price_from: '',
          price_to: '',
          surface_from: '',
          surface_to: '',
          floor: '',
          type: '',
          structure: '',
        },
      }
    },
  computed: {
     filterFilled() {
       // as in @adiga answer, which is great
       return Object.values(this.filter).some(v => v);
     }
  }
```